# Magento: Best way to get url on cms page's custom design

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am currently creating a few pages on a Magento site that are second and third level urls. i.e. home > first level > second level.

I am wondering how to get base url within custom design for the breadcrumbs.

In a normal layout.xml page I can use the following:

```
   <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Home</title>
                    <link>{{baseUrl}}</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>level1</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>first level</label>
                    <title>first level</title>
                    <link>{{baseUrl}}first-level</link>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbName>level2</crumbName>
                <crumbInfo>
                    <label>Second Level</label>
                    <title>Second Level</title>
                </crumbInfo>
            </action>
        </block>
```

Using the `{{baseUrl}}` within the custom design does not work.

Thank you.